# Multiple Private repo cocoapods

Tags: objective-c, xcode, git, dependency-management, cocoapods

I have a private repo lets say 'A' which has some public pods dependencies like AFNetworking and so on. I created a pod spec file for this 'A' and used it in another library project 'B', everything worked fine and library project compiled.

Now I also want to use 'B' (which is also a private repo) in my project I created pod spec file for 'B' and included the only dependency 'A' in it. Did same with Pod file included 'A' as dependency like

```
pod 'A', :git => 'https://github.com/privateRepo/A.git', :tag => 'v1.0.0'
```

and in podspec file like

```
s.dependency     'A', :git => 'https://github.com/privateRepo/A.git', :tag => 'v1.0.0'
```

When I do **pod spec lint .** I get

```
 -> B.podspec
- ERROR | [spec] The specification defined in `B.podspec` could not be loaded.


[!] Invalid `B.podspec` file: [!] Unsupported version requirements. Updating CocoaPods might fix the issue.
#  from B.podspec:18
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  # Dependencies
 >    s.dependency     'A', :git => 'https://github.com/privateRepo/A.git', :tag => 'v1.0.0'
 #  
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

from **pods --version** my cocoapod version is **0.33.1**

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447062/how-do-i-create-a-cocoapods-podspec-that-has-a-dependency-that-exists-outside-of) I think its not possible to do that in cocoapods. Can anybody please help!
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cocoapods does not support dependency from git repo, you must push 'A' to your [Private Spec Repo](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html#-create-a-private-spec-repo), and set dependency in your B.podspec:

```
s.dependency 'A', "~> 1.0"
```

Then lint with `--sources`

```
pod spec lint B.podspec --sources=PrivateSpecRepoNameOrGitURL,master
```