# Podspec. Set s.dependency to download forked repo sources

Tags: cocoapods, podspec

I have a repo that I download via cocoa pods. This repo includes .podspec file which include `s.dependency 'glm', '~> 0.9.4.6'` line.

as I understood it will download it from here: https://github.com/g-truc/glm

I forked glm and now I want to use `s.dependency` that is connected to forked repo of glm. How can I specify it in podspec file to point that I need to download forked glm sources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have CocoaPods override a location of a dependency's dependency in your  [Podfile](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod), i.e. defining `pod 'glm', :git => 'https://github.com/yourUser/yourFork.git'`

You have to make sure the line where you specify your fork comes *before* the line that specifies the pod that uses it as a dependency.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447062/how-do-i-create-a-cocoapods-podspec-that-has-a-dependency-that-exists-outside-of) about this topic, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20936885/cocoapods-and-github-forks) about using forks with CocoaPods conveniently.